# Call dates without losing the date format

Tags: mysql

I have this table

```
Date_data (date format)
03-06-2022
08-08-2021
[NULL]
[NULL]
14-04-2022
25-01-2015
[NULL]
[NULL]
30-01-2019
```

This table has dates and null values .This table is called in a stored procedure, but the "date" format is lost because of the nulls

```
Date_data (text format)
03/06/2022
08/08/2021
[NULL]
[NULL]
14/04/2022
25/01/2015
[NULL]
[NULL]
30/01/2019
```

What I tried (but it still gives in text format):

```
cast(Date_data as date)
date_format (Date_data,%d%m%Y), I also tried date_format (Date_data,%Y%m%d)
date(Date_data)
str_to_date(Date_data,%d%m%Y)
if(Date_date is null, '', Date_data)
if(Date_date is null, '-', Date_data)
```

how can I call the table without losing the format?

Comment: So when you say "date format" you mean you have free text rather than a date column type. [str_to_date()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) does convert from string to date, but you need to get the syntax and format codes right.

Answer (score 0):

I tried on online MySQL complier - https://onecompiler.com/mysql/
Seems to be working for me.

-- create

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
  empId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  dept TEXT NOT NULL,
  birth date,
  birthstr TEXT
);
```

-- insert

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (0001, 'Clark', 'Sales', now(), '2022-11-23');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (0003, 'Ava', 'Sales',null,null);
```

-- fetch

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE dept = 'Sales';
```

| empId | name | dept | birth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Clark | Sales | 2022-11-23 |
| 3 | Ava | Sales | NULL |

--fetch

```
SELECT name, DATE_FORMAT(birth, "%d-%m-%Y") FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

| name | DATE_FORMAT(birth, "%d-%m-%Y") |
| --- | --- |
| Clark | 23-11-2022 |
| Ava | NULL |

If column containing date value in database is text (string), you can then use below query:

```
SELECT name, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(birthstr,"%Y-%m-%d"),"%d-%m-%Y") FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

| name | DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(birthstr,"%Y-%m-%d"),"%d-%m-%Y") |
| --- | --- |
| Clark | 23-11-2022 |
| Ava | NULL |